# How to use Tess4j in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to configure NetBeans(7.2) project to use Tess4J library.
Unfortunately all I get is runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriteParam
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:166)
```

After some time of testing and trying I made a simple Tess4J project in Eclipse and everything is working fine but I don't want to convert whole my project to eclipse.
Both projects are configured the same way, yet NetBeans is refusing to work for some reason.

I've found one possible solution on StackOverflow to put libtesseract302.dll, liblept168.dll and tessdata in jdk/bin folder instead of project folder but I don't have administrator rights on the machine so that is out of the question.

Is there other way to make Tess4J work in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tess4J is itself a NetBeans project. You would only need to open the project, expend the Test Packages, and execute the included unit tests -- no need to copy files anywhere.

Comment: First of all thank you for awesome Tess4J project.
It didn't come to my mind, that I could use source files instead of distributable .jar.
Thanks to you, after looking at your project structure,  I realized that i have not added jna and jai_imageio libraries to my projects build path.
After adding those libraries everything works as intended.

Comment: A tutorial is available: [Development with Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same issue under a windows version of tomcat.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/tess4j/Tesseract

and also

Unable to load library 'libtesseract302' problem (Tesseract is a 32-bit app).

I solved it by adding liblept168.dll and libtesseract302.dll to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\bin (emplacement of the binaries of tomcat) and by linking the jar or the source code provided by Tess4j to my project.

Anyway, under Linux, everything went fine only by referencing the Tess4j project (and with Leptonica installed and data file in the right place)

Hope this helps, enjoy ;)